# Extract only data if their date is > using awk

Tags: linux, date, unix, awk, gawk

I'm trying to extract data log usign awk. Using this :

```
tail -n100 x.log | awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

I have this output :

```
[2015-11-04 16:32:03]
[2015-11-04 17:32:48]
[2015-11-04 17:32:48]
and so on...
```

But now i need to retrive only data > 17:00.
I tried using

```
| awk if($2 > "17:00:00")
```

but i think it can't work.

How can I retrive only data that have $2 > 17:00:00 ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '+$2>=17' file
[2015-11-04 17:32:48]
[2015-11-04 17:32:48]
```

+$2 <==> 0+$2

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this with following command

```
tail -n100 x.log | awk '{print $1,$2}' | grep "2015-11-04 17:"
```

Comment: With this command I only have in output all log at 17.  I need all log > 17 not only at 17.

Comment: I did not downvote, but when you pipe awk to grep you must think that you are calling one process too many. `awk '/2015-11-04 17:/ {print $1, $2}'` is almost equivalent.